# DevExpress DxGrid. Join to values from DataSet in one column

Tags: devexpress, calculated-columns, dxgrid

I am loading data with a services using EntityFrameworkCore and showing data into a DxGrid. I need to combine, join or concatenate to items from my data in one column. I am working on a DevExpress Blazor Template.

This is the way I load my data.
PublicacionesService is my services that it is inject on my .razor page and is declared in Program.cs

```
   IGrid Grid { get; set; }
   protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
   {
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    GridData = await PublicacionesService.ViewPublicaciones.ToListAsync();
 
    PanelVisible = false;
    StateHasChanged();
  
   }
```

Then I have this component

```
   <DxGrid @ref="Grid"
     Data="GridData"
     EditMode="GridEditMode.EditRow"
     CssClass="mw-1100"
     CustomizeElement="Grid_CustomizeElement"
     @oncontextmenu:preventDefault
     EditModelSaving="Grid_EditModelSaving"
     DataItemDeleting="Grid_DataItemDeleting">

     <Columns>
     <DxGridDataColumn FieldName="Numero" Caption="Ver" Width="40px" />

     <DxGridDataColumn " Caption="Expediente"/> // What I expect ExpteNro / ExpteAnio

     <DxGridDataColumn FieldName="Objeto" DisplayFormat="D" Caption="Objeto" />
     <DxGridDataColumn FieldName="Descripcion" Caption="Descripcion" />
     <DxGridDataColumn FieldName="Fecha" Caption="Fecha" Width="140px" />
     </Columns>
    </DxGrid>
```

In a DxGridDataColumn I need to put both ExpteNro and ExpteAnio in a column.
This is my class

```
   public partial class ViewPublicaciones
    {
      public long Id { get; set; }

      public int? ExpteNro { get; set; }

      public int? ExpteAnio { get; set; }

      public DateTime? FechaPres { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I took and easy way and I am not sure if it would make difference using another thing.

```
  public partial class ViewPublicaciones
{
  public long Id { get; set; }

  public int? ExpteNro { get; set; }

  public int? ExpteAnio { get; set; }

  public DateTime? FechaPres { get; set; }

   public string ExpteNroAnio => $"{ExpteNro.ToString() } / 
   {ExpteAnio.ToString()} ";
}

  <DxGridDataColumn FieldName="ExpteNroAnio" Caption="Expediente" 
   Width="120px" />
```

If someone find something else be free to share. JIJIJI.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**